# Python Flask Gunicorn and Nginx configuration on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2

I deployed a [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) application on an [AWS EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html) running [Amazon Linux 2023](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023) operative system.
I worked out everything (always based on the great [microblog tutorial instructions](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux)) and everything is working as expected, except than [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) is unable to directly point to `static` folder.
I deployed several other applications like this one so I know the nginx `app.conf` file is fine:

```
#...

   location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        alias /home/ec2-user/app/static;
        expires 30d;
    }

#...
```

I figured out it must be a permission issue related to `user` and `group` specified in `app.service` file:

```
# ...

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user

# ...
```

In non-amazon linux machines I always used `www-data` group and everything worked fine, I cannot see this group here. How can I solve this out?